# Using Microsoft Bot Framework with ASP.NET Core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, botframework

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.2 app. This app will serve as the endpoint for a bot. In attempt to do this, I've installed the following NuGet packages.

- Microsoft.Bot.Builder (v4.5.2)
- Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs (v4.5.2)

I wanted to migrate the sample found [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/msteams-samples-hello-world-csharp) to Asp.NET Core 2.2. However, it's like the `Activity`, `ConnectorClient`, `EchoBot` and `MessageExtension` classes are gone. Is there a way to replicate this "Hello World" bot in the ASP.NET 2.2 / Bot 4.5 world? Or, is the concept in this "Hello World" dead?

I was unsuccesful in finding "breaking change" details.

Comment: Hello @Learner, looking at the sample you have linked above, its a .NET sample and not .NET Core. So it might be easier to make use of a .NET Core sample to migrate to .NET Core 2.2 rather than .NET. Having said that, I don't think the Activity and ConnectorClient classes should vanish if you are migrating to 2.2. It would be easier to use a .NET Core sample already existing or create a bot from scratch. Let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

I have a sample working for Teams. It’s .net core 2.1, but should not be hard for you to update to 2.2 though. [here](https://github.com/sidecus/zyin.intentbot)